# Entity, Many-To-Many, Add - Ignores Many to Many Table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Reservation>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Chairs)
            .WithMany(e => e.Reservations)
            .Map(m => m.ToTable("ReservationsChairs").MapLeftKey("Reservation_ID").MapRightKey("Chair_ID"));
```

So, the problem is when I try to create a reservation.

I have this Reservation Object:

```
public class Reservation
{
    public Reservation()
    {
        Chairs = new HashSet<Chair>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool IsPaid { get; set; }
    public virtual Planning Planning { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Chair> Chairs { get; set; }
}
```

I attach the chairs (Wich is already created), but, Entity does not use the Many-to-Many table, to bind the Reservation with the Chairs. It actually begins to create the same Chairs in the Chairs table...

**Why does it do this, and what can I do to make it use the Many-To-Many?**

My Chair Object has this:

```
public virtual ICollection<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
```

Above node will be "Null" when I create the Reservation, with the attached Chairs. Is that wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "It actually begins to create the same Chairs in the Chairs table"?

Comment: Well, since It's a Many-to-many, I try to bind a reservation to already existing chairs. Instead of creating the relationships in the Many-to-many table, Entity instead creates the same chairs which already exists in the "Chairs"-table in the Database.

Comment: Could you post the code that makes the link between the reservation and the existing chairs?

Comment: Hi Jessica. I solved the problem - In my Planning object in a Reservation, I have a Hall, that connects the Chairs in an ICollection. As I understand, Entity attached the Chairs inside my Planning, and therefor did see them as new Chairs, and therefor could not map the chairs in the ICollection in the Reservations. I made it work, by setting Hall to null before attaching the Planning, so I could attach the chairs by my self.